# Visual Studio "Local Database Cache": Use SQL Server Tracking vs. LastEditDate/CreationDate columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, caching

I am using Visual Studio's "Local Database Cache" template to cache information in a WinForms application.

In my database, I am using datetime2 columns for LastEditDate and CreationDate and it seems that Visual Studio is not recognizing these fields for synchronization of updates/inserts.

The wizard gives me an option to use SQL Change tracking.  Is it better performance-wise to use the columns or to use SQL change tracking?  How does SQL Change tracking work? Does it use the SQL logs? I usually set my database's recovery model to Simple to avoid having the log file grow out of limits.  Would that limit the ability to use change tracking?